# Is Realm compatible with Exponent

Tags: realm

Is Realm compatible with [Exponent](https://getexponent.com/)?
I tried npm installing Realm for React Native in Windows but ran into the missing files [issue 664](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/674).  I also tried on Ubuntu, but I ran into build errors with Exponent.  I don't have a mac.

Comment: The Exponent website says it uses React Native. Have you tried to use Realm React Native instead of Realm-js?

Comment: Yes, I used the install instructions at: https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#getting-started

Comment: I see no reason why they should not be compatible. The windows issue was unrelated and has been fixed. Perhaps try with the newest released version?

Answer (score 1):

An Exponent developer (ccheever) confirmed today that it is not currently supported:
https://exponentjs.slack.com/archives/random/p1483463744000506

Here is their answer regarding adding support for Realm:

> we might at some point but there are some challenges with versioning
>   etc that make it tricky. We'll likely create a way for you to add
>   native code yourself if you want to use it. I think we're more likely
>   to add SQLite support to Exponent ahead of realm

Comment: adding Realm to Expo would be crazy awesome!

Comment: Dream can't come true. :|

Comment: [They are considering it](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/155) but chances are that it's not in development yet